# CSOM OpenBinaryDirect generates 401 error on office 365

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, csom

I have used same instance of ClientContext inside a RemoteEventReceiver (MinRer.svc.cs) in a provider hosted app to get RootWeb, SubWebs, ListItems and I have added ListItems to lists. It works like a charm. However when I try to copy documents from the RootWeb into a SubWeb it generates 401 unauthorized error when it calls OpenBinaryDirect to get FileInformation  `FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, myFile.ServerRelativeUrl);`

I have now two questions. 
 1. Why it generates 401 error only when it invokes OpenBinaryDirect method and not all other methods regarding webs and lists?
 2. I have solved this problem by adding credentials to the ClientContext. But I want to solve it without using username and password of a user in the code.following is my code:

```
var targetSite = new Uri(rootWeb.Url);
var login = "MyNameh@MyDomain.onmicrosoft.com";
var password = "MyPassword";
var securePassword = new System.Security.SecureString();
foreach (char c in password)
{
    securePassword.AppendChar(c);
}
ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties)
 var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);
 clientContext.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
 FileInformation fileInfo = File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, myFile.ServerRelativeUrl);
```

How do I solve this without using UserName and password in the code? thanks

OBS: This is a RemoteEventReceiver and I have no access to Page instance or Request.

OBS: The logged on user is same that its credentials added to the code.

Comment: What are the permissions for the app?  You can create the context using the TokenHelper class.  `using ( ClientContext cc = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext( properties ) ) { }`

Comment: Yes this is the same context which I have used to get RootWeb, SubWebs, lists and items. but it generates 401 when it calls OpenBinaryDirect. as I described I solved the problem by changing my code to the code I wrote in my question. and the app has SiteCollection and web permissions

Comment: Can you show the code generating the error rather than the code that solved it?

Comment: It is same code I just added credentials to the context

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70151/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-401-unauthorized

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and solved this the following way:
You do not need to use "`OpenBinaryDirect()`" but simply `OpenBinary()`, which does not require an url and does not return a stream directly, but a `ClientResult<Stream>`.

(I retrieved the binary data and filename, reduce your code if you don't need both)

So you simple skip a step and end up using the following:

```
string base64 = null;
var streamX = file.OpenBinaryStream();
context.ExecuteQuery();
var stream = streamX.Value;

byte[] binaryfile = new byte[stream.Length];
stream.Read(binaryfile, 0, (int)stream.Length);
base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(binaryfile);
fileName = file.Name;
return base64;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I save a file from a document library by Id. It's very dirty code, but as POC, it's enough :) Once I save the file, I just create a sytem.io.stream and load it up in a library I need.

```
   [SharePointContextFilter]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Read(int ShowDocId)        
    {


        List<DocumentLibListViewModel> listViewItems = new List<DocumentLibListViewModel>();
        var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);

        using (var context = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
        {
            Web web = context.Web;

            List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

            CamlQuery caml = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
            ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(caml);

            context.Load(items);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            if (items != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    if (ShowDocId == item.Id)
                    {
                        string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                        var streamX = item.File.OpenBinaryStream();
                        context.ExecuteQuery();
                        var stream = streamX.Value;

                        byte[] binaryfile = new byte[stream.Length];
                        stream.Read(binaryfile, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(binaryfile);

                        //save file to a folder
                        var savedUrl = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "\\cache\\" + fileName;

                        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(savedUrl, Convert.FromBase64String(base64));



                        ViewBag.FileLocalUrl = savedUrl;
                    }
                }
            }


            return View();
        }

    }
```